# Does the default allocator zeroize int?

Tags: c++, stl, allocator

When using STL containers, I am not sure whether an int allocated by the default allocator has been zeroized.  The following code indicates 'yes' to the question:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  using namespace std;
  map<int, int> m;
  cout << m[1234] << endl;
}
```

Since no document has confirmed this, I don't dare to take it for granted.

Comment: The allocator will default-construct. This should be relevent: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/877699/default-construction-of-elements-in-a-vector>

Comment: Or, from MSDN: < http://goo.gl/5qvQb >

Comment: The proper term is "default initialized"; e.g. `map<int, std::string>` will default the strings to `""`

Comment: @RobH: In STL containers, "allocator" generally means `std::allocator<>` or its replacement.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore should work now.

Comment: @MSalters To be more long-winded if you wish, accessing the map in the way shown will cause a new value to be created using the (in this case default) allocator, which calls `new`, which will default-construct the newly-created items.

Comment: @RobH: That's quite unlikely: `std::allocator<T>::allocate` only allcoates memory, it doesn't call `new T`. To construct a `T` in that memory, you can then use `std::allocator<T>::construct(ptr, 1)`. That doesn't call `new T` either, since the memory is already allocated. TL;DR: `new T` does in one step what `std::allocator<T>` does in two steps.

Comment: @MSalters I stand corrected. I thought that the allocator was used to allocate memory for new values, but it appears only to be used (in the MSVC implementation) by map's underlying tree. I also notice while I'm in there the source of Luchian's code snippet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll see, inside the implementation of `std::map::operator[]`, if the element is not found at the index, a new one is inserted and returned:

```
ReturnValue = this->insert(where, make_pair(key_value, mapped_type()));
```

where `mapped_type` is the second type, in your case `int`. So yes, it is default-initialized to `0`, since it's inserted as `mapped_type()`.

Comment: I know that an int will be inserted, but I'm not sure whether it's zeroized.  I'm not sure whether `new int` would return a pointer to 0.

Comment: @peter it's not `new int`, it's `int()`, which will yield `0`.

Comment: @peter: That's another question (no; use `new int()` for that). `std::map` doesn't allocate indiviudal `int` objects, but nodes which each hold a `pair<Key, MappedValue>`

Comment: actually `new int` is bound to yield a pointer to an unpredictable value; `new int()` will yield a pointer to zero as `int()` is an `int` initialized to zero.

Answer (score 6):

The standard guarantees that objects created as a result of using the subscript operator are default constructed. Whether the default constructor for any particular class zeroes the members you expect to be zeroed is up to theclass. For classes without constructors members are default constructed and default construction fundamental types amounts to setting the to their version of "zero".

Note, this has **nothing** to do with allocators! ... and it is pretty safe to assume that tbe allocators leave the memory untouched, except possibly dedicated debugging allocators (or allocators written by people tricked into thinking that zeroing the memory might be Good Thing rather than a device hiding bugs). ... and the debugging allocator wouldn't zero the memory but fill it with a recognizable pattern ( e.g. resulting in `0xdeadbeef` when viewed in hexadecimal).

Comment: +1 for making the distinction between allocation and the rest clear.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this: **8.5.5 Initializers** 
C++ Standard - ANSI ISO IEC 14882 2003

To zero-initialize an object of type T means:
if T is a scalar type (3.9), the object is set to the value of 0 (zero) converted to T;

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the default allocator template will use `new int()` to default-ininitialize an int to 0, according to C++ ISO standard 14882:2003. Chapter 8.5, Clause-5,7:

> To **zero-initialize** an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a scalar type (3.9), the object is set to the value of 0 (zero) converted to T;
>
> To **value-initialize** an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a class type (clause 9) with a user-declared constructor (12.1), then the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
> - if T is a non-union class type without a user-declared constructor, then every non-static data member and base-class component of T is value-initialized;
> - if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
> - otherwise, the object is zero-initialized
>
> To **default-initialize** an object of type T means:
>
> - if T is a non-POD class type (clause 9), the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
> - if T is an array type, each element is default-initialized;
> - otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.
>
> An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., (), shall be value-initialized.

There are also similar rules in C++11 ISO Standard draft.